# How is deep copy different from creating new instance with same values in java?

Tags: java, clone, deep-copy

I know what is shallow copy and deep copy, however I still don't understand what's the difference between creating a deep copy with `clone` method and creating new instance with same values of other instance. or creating static function in `main` that does this copy.

For example, let's say I have class A with integers `x,y`. and I created an instance called `a1` and initialized it with `x=1, y=2`:

```
A a1 = new A(1,2);
```

What's the difference between a deep copy (using clone method) and doing one of the following?:

```
A a2 = new A(a1.x, a1.y);
A a3 = new A(a1);
```

Comment: The `clone()` method was one of those that early designers of Java thought would be useful, but in fact is hardly ever used. It is preferable to use a copy constructor. See the item "Override clone judiciously" in Josh Bloch's "Effective Java".

Comment: In the case of a class whose fields are all int, the default Object.clone() is the same as a copy constructor, because a shallow copy and a deep copy are identical operations.  However, if a class has non-primitive fields whose types are mutable, the default Object.clone() will only perform a shallow copy.  As you seem to surmise, overriding clone() to do a deep copy and writing a copy constructor that does a deep copy are essentially equivalent.